# Installing libCURL on VC++11 - Unresolved External Symbols Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, libcurl

I've spent far more time than I would have liked attempting to get libcURL working on VC++11. I followed the steps here: http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/

Those steps appear to have worked for others on the board, however I am getting unresolved external symbol errors and it will not compile. The errors look like this:

```
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init referenced in function "int __cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAHXZ)  C:\Users\ryant_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Phase 2\Phase 2\LIBCURLFIRST.obj   Phase 2
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_perform referenced in function "int __cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAHXZ)   C:\Users\ryant_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Phase 2\Phase 2\LIBCURLFIRST.obj   Phase 2
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "int __cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAHXZ)    C:\Users\ryant_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Phase 2\Phase 2\LIBCURLFIRST.obj   Phase 2
```

Here is my linker settings:

Include Directories:

```
C:\thirdparty\vs2012\x86\libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc\include\curl
```

Library Directories:

```
C:\thirdparty\vs2012\x86\libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc\lib\Debug
```

Additional Dependencies:

```
C:\thirdparty\vs2012\x86\libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-svc\lib\Debug\curllib.lib
```

Has anyone else experienced this and have a solution or a thought? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Please post some of the mentioned error reports.

Comment: Sounds like you've forgotten to add some libraries in the linker config, but yes errors would be helpful. EDIT: Yep looks like it. Check your linker options.

Comment: Do you see any issues in my linker options I still haven't been able to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **libcurl.lib** (release) or **libcurld.lib** (debug) as an Additional Dependency on the Linker Input tab of your project properties.

Comment: I've added curllib.lib... not sure if there is a file called libcurl.lib I assume you meant curllib

Comment: The distro I'm using in VC++ requires libcurl(d).lib - yours may be different.

Comment: Yea the documents all say to link in curllib.lib and I don't have any files called libcurl.lib on my computer